# RuntimeException when Upgrading Magento 2

Tags: magento2, upgrade

I've not done an awful lot with M2 yet, I'm a sysadmin guy, but I've been dropped in it a little this week with a colleague off sick.

Anyway.  I need upgrade a M2 site.  First to 2.0.16 and then to 2.1.9.  The 2.0.16 upgrade went fine but the 2.1.9 upgrade isn't working for me.  When I run the upgrade through composer I get...

[RuntimeException]
Class Companyname\Modulename\Model\Rewrite\Customer\Classname does not exist

Now I'm pretty sure that this is a bespoke module that was developed for the client, but that's all I know.  Do I need to update something to tell M2 it will work for that version?

I've tried clearing cache, resetting permissions and whatever else I could find whilst searching, but nothing fixes the issue.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Were you able to solve your issue?

Comment: @Neo Unfortunately not.

Answer (score 0):

You should do following ;

1) Check if Companyname\Modulename path exists under app/code of Magento's root.

2) If yes, try running following commands from Magento's root ;

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade

php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy


sudo chmod 777 -R var pub
```

3) If no, then go to your magento's db , which you can know from `app/etc/env.php`
and in table `setup_module` search for `Companyname_Modulename` if it exists, then delete the row and run commands mentioned in step 2.

Let me know if there is any problem

Comment: Thank you for this but it didn't help.